# How do I list associated attributes in my Rails 3 view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Customers model:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :phone_numbers
end
```

and a Phone Numbers model

```
class PhoneNumber < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end
```

In my view, I'm doing this:

```
<table id="customerSearch">
  <tr>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

and here is my controller for this action:

```
def index
  @customers = Customer.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => 'last_name')
  flash.now[:notice] = 'Enter customer last or first name. Fields are case-sensitive.'
end
```

In the table in my view, I want to show the first phone number found for each customer listed in a phone number column - like:

```
Last Name    first Name    Phone

Smith        John          3258889322
Jones        Davey         3412555232
```

I've come up with multiple solutions to this problem, but none was very elegant. There must be a 'Rails Way' to do this that is really snazzy, as this seems like a common situation for a web application developer to be faced with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view:

```
<table id="customerSearch">
  <tr>
    <th>Last name</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= customer.last_name %></td>
    <td><%= customer.first_name %></td>
    <td><%= customer.phone_numbers.first.number if customer.phones.exists? %>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', customer %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_customer_path(customer) %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Your association will take care of creating those phone-number-related attribute accessors for you. You can see all of the methods that are created for you with a `has_many` association [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_many-association-reference).

Comment: when I do that, I get something like: #<PhoneNumber:0xb66c80c0> in the phone number column in my view table. So, I guess I have the right object in my view now, but I need the 'number' attribute of that object, since that is my actual phone number. How would I do that? I tried chaining 'number' on the end of first, but of course first has no method called number.

Comment: I don't know your db schema, so suppose that PhoneNumber has an attribute "value" where it saves the actual phone number. You would output it like customer.phone_numbers.first.value . I suggest you fire up the rails console in a terminal and try to do Customer.first.phone_numbers.first.inspect to see which attribute(s) you want.

Comment: Hey! that worked! I did: customer.phone_numbers.first.number and that got me the right number. I guess I had tried calling number on first earlier and it didn't work for whatever reason, so I assumed it wouldn't this time. Thanks!

Comment: D'oh! I missed that last method. I've updated the answer, just for anybody stumbling onto this.